# Get access to HttpActionContext outside of my Web API 2 Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Inside my Controller class I can do this:

```
var userId = this.ActionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
```

But I have a soap header that I want to pass this value into.  The behavior that uses the soap header is setup using my dependency injection.  So while it is created for each call, it is not created in the Controller.

So I am wondering, is there a way to get access to Web API 2's HttpActionContext outside the controller.  Ideally I would want something like this:\

```
HttpActionContext.CurrentInstance.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
```

But of course `CurrentInstance` does not exist as a static member of `HttpActionContext`.

**But is there some other way to get this without the Controller?**

Comment: If the goal is to get access the principal then you can either get it form the thread or httpcontext.

Comment: Thread.CurrentPrincipal is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access identity name using following

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: This only works if you are bringing in System.Web and isn't advisable for perf reasons

Comment: This does not answer the stated question (get HttpActionContext statically) and will throw an exception in some hosting scenarios.